# Why does my solution to leetcode 322 Coin Change timeout

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> um;
public:
    int coinChange(vector<int>& coins, int amount) {
        if (amount == 0)
            return 0;

        auto it = um.find(amount);
        if (it != um.end())
            return it->second;

        int ret = -1;

        for (int c : coins)
        {
            int n = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                int a = amount - n * c, m = 0;
                if (a < 0)
                    break;
                if (a > 0)
                    m = coinChange(coins, a);
                if (m != -1)
                {
                    if (ret == -1)
                        ret = m + n;
                    else
                        ret = std::min(ret, m + n);
                }
                n++;
            }
        }

        um[amount] = ret;
        return ret;
    }
};
```

As far as I can tell, it is very similar to the most upvoted solution, it even constructs the same hashtable. However I get timeout at arbitrary inputs.
I am not able to find any errors locally.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Edit:

I include the problem statement:

You are given coins of different denominations and a total amount of money amount. Write a function to compute the fewest number of coins that you need to make up that amount. If that amount of money cannot be made up by any combination of the coins, return -1.

Example:
coins = [1, 2, 5], amount = 11
return 3 (11 = 5 + 5 + 1)

The approach:

Use dynamic programming (recursion + memoization). For an amount, try every coin as long as the amount is positive. For the above example:

```
S(11) = 1 + S(10) | 2 + S(9) | 3 + S(8) | ... | 11 + S(0) | //try coin 1

        1 + S(9) | 2 + S(7) | 3 + S(5) | ... | 5 + S(1) | //try coin 2

        1 + S(6) | 2 + S(1) //try coin 5
```

Pardon the confusion around this question, I believe my implementation of the above idea has some bug but I have a difficult time finding it.

Comment: Can a ever be 0? Looks like if it is 0 your code loops forever.

Comment: Try to use a debugger and step through the code...

Comment: If you are to pursue a career that of a software developer then you are well advised to stay away from those bogus _competitive programming_ sites. They spread toxic knowledge and contribute nothing.

Comment: @mame98, I did that, I find no problem when running a single input, nor locally nor in the web interface.

Comment: @ron Some stupid recruiters seem to judge similar ways nowadays? "O tempora o mores"

Comment: Those competitive programming sites accept any crap program that happens to pass the test.  They don't really teach how to properly write a program.

Comment: You probably did not try the same test case.

Comment: @Ron, leetcode was working pretty well until now :( At least they are useful in preparing for interviews since many companies ask these kind of questions...

Comment: @gg.kaspersky In that case - walk away from those interviews.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky oh ok, then ignore my comment ;)

Comment: Seems like you are missing several `break;`

Comment: @gg.kaspersky No problemz found? You're using the debugger wrong most probably, or you don't apply the relevant test cases to your code.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky *As far as I can tell, it is very similar to the most upvoted solution* -- So was the most upvoted solution written in C++?  If not, then this is a case where learning C++ properly supersedes writing anything that looks like some other language.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, the similarity is in the algorithmic idea. The most upvoted was a Java program, which I ported to C++ and submitted and it got accepted, however my C++ solution does not work, making me believe I have a bug, but I can not find it.

Comment: I mentioned 2 possible bugs. My advice to you is go back and use a debugger and try more test cases. Single step through the test cases and make sure the algorithm is doing what you expect.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please explain the problem and the approach you adopted ..Apart from SO I am not regular to any other . online site

Comment: @HariomSingh, I made an edit, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Later edit: I was wrong**

I noticed that the running times were still too high for the C version, so that was not the issue. I managed to get all the tests from Leetcode and found the problem.

For the test case coins: {3, 7, 405, 436} and amount: 8839 my implementation would make 18744855 calls while the most popular only 34486.

This is because, for each coin, I try to put it into amount as many times as it is possible (the `while (true)` loop), and after each try I make a recursive call. It goes like this (for coins = {1} and amount = 3):

```
S(3) = min{1 + S(2), 2 + S(1), 3 + S(0)}

S(2) = min{1 + S(1), 2 + S(0)}

S(1) = min{1 + S(0)}

S(0) = 0
```

However it is sufficient to try the coin only once and let the recursive call handle the rest, like the popular solution does:

```
S(3) = min{1 + S(2)}

S(2) = min{1 + S(1)}

S(1) = min{1 + S(0)}

S(0) = 0
```

**Previous answer:**

I have ported the same exact solution to C, and that got accepted, so I assume it is some problem in the Leetcode infrastructure.

```
int coinChange_(int* coins, int coinsSize, int *um, int amount) {
    if (amount == 0)
        return 0;

    if (um[amount] != 0)
        return um[amount];

    int ret = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < coinsSize; i++)
    {
        int c = coins[i];
        int n = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            int a = amount - n * c, m = 0;
            if (a < 0)
                break;
            if (a > 0)
                m = coinChange_(coins, coinsSize, um, a);
            if (m != -1)
            {
                if (ret == -1)
                    ret = m + n;
                else
                    ret = m + n < ret ? m + n : ret;
            }
            n++;
        }
    }

    um[amount] = ret;
    return ret;
}

int coinChange(int* coins, int coinsSize, int amount) {
    int *um = calloc(amount + 1, sizeof *um);
    int ret = coinChange_(coins, coinsSize, um, amount);
    free(um);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Its good that you found out the solution.but in c++ version you have used unordered_map and finding element adds to time complexity

Comment: If you would have incrementally ported the code to C++ instead of jumping straight into trying to get `unordered_map` to work, you would have seen that your `coinChange` function would probably run faster if `um` was a non-local `std::vector` and just called `resize()` to resize the vector.  Right now, you're calling `calloc` and `free`, which adds to the time taken if `coinChange` is called multiple times.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I am aware of that. I discovered the real issue and updated the answer. It was a subtle flaw in the algorithm.